# Command failed git update-git-for-windows

Tags: git

I'm trying to update my Git and by typing the command:

```
$ git update-git-for-windows
```

It displays the following error:

```
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain
More details here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and
how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.
```

Note: This problem started to appear after updating Windows to 1909.

Comment: Not an answer (and a potential security risk!): you could create a `~/.curlrc` file with a line containing `insecure`. This will **disable** TLS verification for **all** curl invocations.

Comment: Are you executing this from behind a corporate firewall by any chance? That was the root cause for me.

Answer (score 32):

I am using Kaspersky antivirus, and it was blocking the update.

I just disabled the internet and file protection and the update command worked properly.
After that you might just enable the antivirus full protection.

Comment: How to proceed when you can't disable antivirus (e.g. at work)?

Comment: Yep, it's the antivirus that blocked the SSL verification.

Comment: This worked for me as well, using Avast Free Antivirus. Right clicking the icon in the task bar, and turning off the protection for 10 minutes under "Avast protection control" did the job of eliminating this error and updating git properly.

Answer (score 8):

Or just look into the latest docs https://git-scm.com/download/win and run

```
winget install --id Git.Git -e --source winget
```

in PowerShell.

Comment: Encountered `Installer failed with exit code: 1`. After inspecting the logs, it became clear that the failure was caused by an open instance of Git Bash. The install succeeded after closing the instance and re-running the command.

Comment: @Chrisuu your suggestion worked like charm. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I bumped into this exact error message which occurred while on my corporate machine + VPN after running `git update-git-for-windows` in git bash.

### Windows Solution (worked for me):

1. Identify the location of my **ca-bundle.crt** on my machine
2. Navigate to `C:\Users\[UserName]\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\mingw64\bin` in another Explorer window
3. Drag and drop a copy of the **ca-bundle.crt** found in step 1 into the ...\mingw64\bin folder from step 2.
4. Rename the new copy of the **ca-bundle.crt** to **curl-ca-bundle.crt**
5. Close all instances of git bash, reopen git bash, run `git update-git-for-windows`

The download was successful for me after completing these steps. Hopefully this saves another weary soul some time with this issue.

Comment: Where can you usually find ca-bundle.crt?

Comment: Hi Neo, (at least on Windows) you may be able to find your corporate bundle.crt in your C: drive -> Users -> your username folder. Of course the exact name and location can vary widely based on where you work and the OS you use.

Comment: I tried this and it did not work.  I had no Git/mingw64/bin under the Programs folder in step 2.  So i added those and completed rest of steps but to no avail.  still got same error

Answer (score 2):

None of the solutions provided worked for me. What did work was:

1. Identify the installation path of your Git
2. Enter the **mingw64\bin** folder
3. Open your **git-update-git-for-windows** file
4. Edit both curl commands available and add the **--insecure** or **-k** parameter
5. Run again git update-git-for-windows

I'm still being blocked at installation probably because our EPM software but at least I can run the update command.

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest you use [Chocolatey package manager](https://chocolatey.org/) to upgrade git:

```
choco upgrade git
```

Comment: Chocolatey is very useful in a not controlled environnement but if your company have an EPM software probably it will block installation and/or updates. I was using it before the adoption of an EPM but now it blocks everything choco-related.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by these steps:

1. Visit https://curl.se/docs/caextract.html
2. Download last **cacert-2022-04-26.pem**
3. Rename to **curl-ca-bundle.crt**
4. Move the **curl-ca-bundle.crt** to **C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin**

Then run again **git update-git-for-windows**

Comment: does not work for me

Answer (score 0):

This normally happens when a firewall inspects the content of https connections. It then issues new certificates based on a company root certificate. So what worked for me was adding this root certificate to Git's **ca-bundle.crt** file found in `C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\ssl\certs` or `C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\etc\ssl\certs`.

Answer (score 0):

I had `avast Antivirus` in the Windows.

I had to disable `avast Antivirus` to update `git` from:

```
git update-git-for-windows
```

> Make sure to disable antivirus in your windows. Once download is completed you may want to activate antivirus to secure your computer